# F# numeric associations

Tags: f#, numeric

I have a numeric association for a custom type as follows:

```
let DiffNumerics =
{ new INumeric<Diff> with
      member op.Zero = C 0.0
      member op.One = C 1.0
      member op.Add(a,b) = a + b
      member op.Subtract(a,b) = a - b
      member op.Multiply(a,b) = a * b
      member ops.Negate(a) = Diff.negate a
      member ops.Abs(a) = Diff.abs a
      member ops.Equals(a, b) = ((=) a b)
      member ops.Compare(a, b) = Diff.compare a b
      member ops.Sign(a) = int (Diff.sign a).Val
      member ops.ToString(x,fmt,fmtprovider) =  failwith "not implemented"
      member ops.Parse(s,numstyle,fmtprovider) = failwith "not implemented"
}

GlobalAssociations.RegisterNumericAssociation(DiffNumerics)
```

It works fine in f# interactive, but crashes when I run, because .ElementOps is not filled correctly for a matrix of these types. Any ideas why this might be?

EDIT:

In fsi, the code

```
let A = dmatrix [[Diff.C 1.;Diff.C 2.;Diff.C 3.];[Diff.C 4.;Diff.C 5.;Diff.C 6.]]
let B = matrix [[1.;2.;3.];[4.;5.;6.]]
```

gives:

```
> A.ElementOps;;
val it : INumeric<Diff> = FSI_0003.NewAD+DiffNumerics@258
> B.ElementOps;;
val it : INumeric<float> = Microsoft.FSharp.Math.Instances+FloatNumerics@115
>
```

in the debugger A.ElementOps shows:

```
'(A).ElementOps' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
```

and, for the B matrix:

```
Microsoft.FSharp.Math.Instances+FloatNumerics@115
```

So somehow the DiffNumerics isn't making it to the compiled program.

Comment: It is usually helpful to post the entirety of the error message (either compile time or run time) that you are getting. Anonymizing it is fine of course.

Comment: `[1.;2.;3]` would not compile

Comment: should it be `ElementOps()` - the string returned looks like a delegate

Comment: John - probably is a delegate (I came to F# without c#, so I'm not sure). If so, then I'm missing the delegate for the A type - so GlobalAssociations.RegisterNumericAssociation(DiffNumerics) is not getting run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer - but it solves the problem.

The GlobalAssociations.RegisterNumericAssociation(DiffNumerics) was somehow not getting run. If I add an initialisation function which runs it - it fails with an error, saying that that DiffNumerics is already loaded, but thereafter I'm OK. If I don't call the initialisation() (which fails because it says it's already loaded) then it isn't loaded and ElementOps returns the error above.

Not time to work out what is actually going on...

N